# SQLalechemy query returns object instead of value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to get all the values from the row for a query, however when I run the below code it returns an object instead of the values:

```
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)  #
session = Session()

class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player_alc'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    country= Column(String(50))
    first_name = Column(String(50))
    last_name= Column(String(50))


class Player_Mapping(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player_external_id_mapping_alc'
    external_id = Column(String(50), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    external_source_name = Column(String(50), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player_alc.id'))
    Player = relationship("Player", back_populates="player_mapping")

Player.player_mapping = relationship(
"Player_Mapping",  back_populates="Player")


query= session.query(Player_Mapping).filter_by(external_id=external_id, external_source_name=external_source_name).one()
```

Above code returns the following value for the query:

> ORM_classes.Player_Mapping object at 0x0000016119E24D30>

Answer (score 2):

You *are* asking for the object, right here:

```
session.query(Player_Mapping)
```

You can access all the fields through the returned object though, for example `query.Player` or `query.external_source_name`.

If you want to explicitly get the columns rather than an object, you can use:

```
session.query(Player_Mapping.Player, Player_Mapping.external_source_name)
```